# Connect Mainframe Using Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, soapui, bluezone

I am currently working on a web service project which is exposed..  I need to automate the below process

```
Step 1: Connect Mainframe and collect test data from the Mainframe and storing data in xls.
Step 2: Run the Soap Request and Verify that the response is 200
Step 3: Connect Mainframe again and Extract each parameter from Response and validate those against in MF data.
```

Related to Webservice Test, i have worked on Soap UI.. Step 1 can be optional may be i can run a batch jobs to get that..

Step 2 and Step 3 is it possible in Soap UI itself.  I am using Rocket Bluezone Emulator to test this..

There is a way that I can write a vb script and call that vbscript using groovy that is the least option..

Is there any other way that i can connect Rocket Bluezone using Java/Groovy to achieve this instead of running separately vbscript.

Comment: Why it is downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I would guess people have because it's pretty vague and not showing any specific information.  Yes, it's possible to make network calls or system calls in Java/Groovy.  However, your question doesn't give enough information for people to help any more than saying "yes it's possible".

Comment: A better option would be to connect to the data on the mainframe, if it is in a database that has a JDBC driver. Perhaps it is DB2, then you could. Sounds like you want to use Groovy -> VBScript -> Emulator -> Data, and that is many layers of complexity. Possible, probably. Advisable, no.

Answer (score 1):

To answer a part of your question, you can call VBScript from Groovy.

A script:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    WScript.Echo "Missing parameters"
end if

function func(parm)
    Wscript.Echo("You sent " & parm )
    func = "You sent " & parm
end function

func(Wscript.Arguments(0))
```

You can call it, pass a parameter, and get the return value from Groovy like this:

```
def script = "src/myScript.vbs"
def exe = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cscript.exe"
def parm = "Hello"
def cmd = "${exe} ${script} \"${parm}\""
def proc = cmd.execute()
def outputStream = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
println outputStream.toString()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. without vbscript i am trying to find out by Java/Groovy can this achievable//

Comment: You don't say what is on the mainframe, CICS, Natural, or what. I really suggest trying to get access to the DB if it is at all possible. Rocket Bluezone is scriptable with VBScript, and I have shown you how you can call that with Groovy.

Comment: Thanks.. it is CICS.. we dont have DB2.

Comment: If we have multiple functions, how it will identify to which function to go to?

Comment: Put each function in a separate script.

Comment: Here is my code.. if parm is removed and running the vbs file.. then it is running.. but from groovy script i am running.. it is just printing "Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."              Function func(parm)
Set Host = CreateObject( "BZWhll.WhllObj" )
ResultCode = Host.Connect( "A" )
If ResultCode <> 0 Then
   Host.MsgBox "Error connecting to session A!", 4096
End If
Host.SendKey region
Host.WaitReady 10, 1
Host.SendKey "<ENTER>"
Wscript.Echo("You sent " & region )
End Function
func(Wscript.Arguments(0))

Comment: if Wscript.Echo("You sent " & region ) is given after the function it is printing value.. but further actions is not running